# retrieving user id in cakephp view

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to retrieve the user id in a cakephp view, what's the best practise to achieve that?
since `Auth->user('id')`  is only usable in controller, what's to be used in views?

Edit :

I fixed it by using this in the controller:

```
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->set("user_id",$id);
```

then in the view of the controller I just retrieve $user_id.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Session helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1465/Session).

```
var $helpers = array('Session'); // controller

// view
$this->Session->read('Auth.User'); // returns complete user record
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.email'); // returns email for logged in user
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything *wrong* with the approach in your controller;  but the functionality is already built in to Cake, so saves reinventing the wheel and keeps your code clearer for other developers.

Comment: When user delete someone,i need to ask user password again with javascript prompt .. and need to check user password in view of js.. `this->Session->read('Auth.User.password') is not ..?